# Updating a Global Variable on Page Load VB.net in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, global-variables, global, global-asax

I am trying to set a variable on every page load automatically from the Global.asax file.

I thought I could do this from `Application_BeginRequest` but it doesn't seem to be working.

The variable is set from a database, essentially I am doing a very quick call to the DB to check if I need to do something else. I can't go into the detail now but can't use a cache for this.

So, I have tried many ideas, but not getting anywhere, here are two most logical to my mind:

1: Setting the variable in `Application_BeginRequest`

```
Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication
    Shared Property MyVar as String
    Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        MyVar = CallToDatabase()
    End Sub
End Class
```

2: Setting the variable at the start of the Global.asax file:

```
Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication
    Shared Property MyVar as String = CallToDatabase()         
End Class
```

Of these two, these are the problems:

Version (1) doesn't seem to set the variable at all, when trying to access I am getting an empty value.

Version (2) does work, but the value is static across page loads, meaning that if I refresh or move to another page, the value remains the same even when I know it should have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance.  Create a class (BasePage) and every page can inherit this base page.  In the Page_Load (or Pre_Init) of the base page, put your DB check.  This will allow you to check on some pages, but not all (if that is ever necessary).